# Append truncated text with "Read more" or "Show more" (or other?)

Tags: text, grammar, verb

Let's say I've got a block of text on a page that I want to truncate to save 'real estate' on the page. I'll crop the copy (not mid word if I can help it) and add an ellipsis (...) and a hyperlink.

What should the hyperlink say?

If I go for 'Read more' does it *feel* like the computer telling me what to do? 
If I go for 'Show more' does it *feel* like I'm telling the computer what to do?

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "Read More" and "Show More" are pretty clear to mean clicking on them would reveal more text. Adding an ellipsis (...) when the text becomes truncated would also clearly indicate the functionality of "Read More" / "Show More".